# The method main cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type

Tags: java, static

In my coding, parent class `Shape` is an abstract object and it has several child classes. My coding is as follow:

```
import java.util.Random;

abstract class Shape {
    protected Color color;
    protected Point point;

    public Shape(Color color, Point point) {
        this.color = color;
        this.point = point;
    }
    public abstract String Type();
}

class Rectangle extends Shape {
    public Rectangle(Color color, Point point) {
        super(color, point);
    }

    public String Type() {
        return "Rectangle";
    }
    class Triangle extends Shape {
        public Triangle(Color color, Point point) {
            super(color, point);
        }
        public String Type() {
            return "Triangle";
        }
    }
    class Eclipse extends Shape {
        public Eclipse(Color color, Point point) {
            super(color, point);
        }
        public String Type() {
            return "Eclipse";
        }
    }
    public class ShapeTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Color color = new Color(50, 100, 150);
            Point point = new Point(50, 50);
            Shape[] theShape = {
                new Rectangle(color, point),
                    new Triangle(color, point),
                    new Eclipse(color, point)
            };
            Shape shapechoice;
            Random select = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                shapechoice = theShape[select.nextInt(theShape.length)];
                System.out.println("The " + (i + 1) + "type you chose is: " + shapechoice.Type());;
            }
        }
    }
```

Eclipse says "The method main cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type" at `public static void main(String[] args){` , but i thought this syntax should be a commonly used format which is kinda fixed? Why at here i need to remove "static"?  Sorry I'm new at java and might be blur for this.

Comment: Move you main to outer class or readjust your code.

Comment: You cannot have the main method in an inner class. Move it to the outer class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `main()` method from the inner class `ShapeTest`. You can't put it in a non-static non-top-level class. In your existing code, you could put `main()` in `Rectangle`, or you could move `ShapeTest` to be a top-level class.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `class` declaration like so:

```
class Rectangle extends Shape {

}
```

This is a top-level class.

Next you have an **inner class** declaration:

```
class Rectangle extends Shape {
    public class ShapeTest {
    }
}
```

This is an inner class because it is not `static`. It is within the instance context of `Rectangle` and has an implicit reference to `Rectangle.this`.

Next you have a static method declaration:

```
class Rectangle extends Shape {
    public class ShapeTest {
        public static void main(String[] args){
        }
    }
}
```

This `static` declaration is within an instance declaration of `ShapeTest`. This is not allowed.

So either declare `ShapeTest` as a static nested class (weird and confusing to have `main` in a static nested class):

```
class Rectangle extends Shape {
    public static class ShapeTest {
        public static void main(String[] args){
        }
    }
}
```

Or declare `ShapeTest` in its own `ShapeTest.java` file as a top level class (much better):

```
public class ShapeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your `main()` method to a top level class or static class. Either move the `main()` method to the class `Rectangle` (as suggested by Elliott) or make your class `ShapeTest` `static`, e.g.

```
public class Rectangle {
    public static class ShapeTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call the class with `java Rectangle.ShapeTest`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the static `main` method in (A) a top-level or (B) static class. You have put the `main` method in a regular nested class, which is dependent on the instance of the class it is defined in.

Try adding the keyword `static` to the definitions of `Triangle`, `Eclipse` and `ShapeTest`, like so:
`public static class ShapeTest`.

BTW 1: you would be better off creating multiple files.
BTW 2: why are `Triangle`, `Eclipse` and `ShapeTest` inner classes of Rectangle?